# Are there any frameworks for managing the exchange of XLM between two XLM addresses when the receiving end party address isn't known?

Tags: xlm, transactions

I have been working on a "bot" for operating on various websites. I want the bot to be able to accept and send XLM between two parties, even if the receiving party doesn't yet have a XLM address.

The idea is to build a way to ask questions to the community and get rewarded for the right answers. If people want, they can put a "bounty" on the question being asked, and then promise that the "bounty" is paid out to the best answer.

Beyond creating an interim XLM address (which seems risky

Comment: can you clarify your question? On one hand the main question seems to be related to exchanging (so bidirectional?) tokens 'XLR' (but I maybe you mean XLM) - but I am not sure what is being exchanged. Main question seems to be asking about the design of a "tip bot" of some sort - but it's truncated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great idea but with high security risks. You can ask the user to provide the public key to get the reward or to generate a new address/secret so you can send them the money without ever talking back to the server after the account creation, also the code must be publicly available, peer reviewed and approved by the community to gain more trust. People should be able to transfer the funds easily to other private accounts they own so new accounts will be temporary in nature.

Remember that trust is the most important aspect when dealing with users money.

Regarding the SDK, if the account does not exist you should use the 'createAccount' method for that purpose or the transaction will be rejected if sent as 'payment' to a non-existing account.

HTH